# Given protocol, username, password, hostname, port and path how to get a URL

Tags: java, url, encoding

Given protocol, username, password, hostname, port and path what is the easiest way to get a (properly encoded) URL

There are similar questions already asked but:

- [java.net.URI](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) seems to not allow to pass the password
- [java.net.URLEncoder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) makes me split the path into components and encode each

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow...usually a url is protocol://hostname:port/ (based on your parameters). Where does username + password fit in?

Comment: @Elite: Usually, yes, but the URL can also include username/password also (`scheme://user:password@hostname:port/path`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just connecting to the URL then take a look at [this sample](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=10).

Comment: I am also looking for other protocols like smb and ftp

Answer (score 0):

For FTP:
ftp://user:pass@hostname:port/path

For HTTP:
http://hostname:port/path?pass=mypassword&username=myname

You can add as many parameters in the http url as u want, split them by & signs.